# Firebase Phone Authentication OTP not Auto Fill in EditText

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-edittext, one-time-password

Firebase Phone Authentication sent otp automatically not fill in edittext. otp is manually entered in edittext. how do automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification with user action?

Otp.kt

```
private fun sendVerificationCode(phone : String){


    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
        .setPhoneNumber(phone)       // Phone number to verify
        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
        .setCallbacks(callbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)




}

private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
    override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {

        binding.btnOtpVerify.visible(true)
        binding.progressbarVerify.visible(false)
        val code = p0.smsCode

        if(code != null){
            binding.etOtpView.setText(code)

            VerifyVerificationCode(code)

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(p0)
        }
    }

    override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
        binding.btnOtpVerify.visible(true)
        binding.progressbarVerify.visible(false)

        Toast.makeText(this@OtpVerification,p0.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onCodeSent(p0: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(p0, p1)

        binding.btnOtpVerify.visible(true)
        binding.progressbarVerify.visible(false)
        storedVerificationID = p0
        resendingToken = p1


    }

}
```

Comment: I faced the same issue so make sure your OTP SMS should be less than 52 characters and if your sim carrier is Airtel then try to test with another number. By reducing the SMS limit to 52 my issue gets resolved for other carriers but for the airtel sim issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled SafetyNet thing [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification) on google.

For the autofill editText work with the code inside the function `onVerificationCompleted`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are using Firebase PhoneAuth to verify the phone number and send an OTP via the Firebase server, and you need a workflow to detect the incoming SMS containing the OTP and auto-fill your EditText with this OTP.

To enable automatic OTP detection, you can use the SmsRetriever API and the related SMS User Consent API.

Well-explained documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/choose-an-api). (Contains further links to a reference implementation that pretty much works out of the box, so I'm not including that code here.)

Be sure to choose the appropriate API for your use case.